# Анимация меню в Wordpress

Tags: javascript, анимация

Есть сайт на вордпресе. И есть там такое меню с кнопкой.

```html
<button class="menu-toggle" aria-controls="primary-menu" aria-expanded="false">Menu</button>
```

При нажатии на кнопку aria-expanded меняется на true и меню выпадает.

```html
<button class="menu-toggle" aria-controls="primary-menu" aria-expanded="true">Menu</button>
```

Еще при изминении появляется класс toggled.

```html
<nav id="site-navigation" class="main-navigation container toggled" role="navigation">
```

Хочу сделать чтобы меню выезжало плавно. Сначала пытался добавить 
transition: width 2s;
В стилях, но ничего не получилось.
Как найти JS в через хром и добавить анимацию?